# Prove $\forall z\in H$, $\frac{|f'(z)|}{Im f(z)} ≤ \frac{1}{Im f(z)}$ given f holomorphic using Schwarz Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorph

Let H stand for the upper half-plane in the complex plane C. Suppose that $f:H\rightarrow H$ holomorphic. How can I use Schwarz Lemma to show that $\forall z\in H$, $\frac{|f'(z)|}{Im \,f(z)} ≤
\frac{1}{Im\, z}$ , and that if equality holds at some $z_0 \in H$, then $\forall z \in H$, $f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, for some $a, b, c, d \in R, ad − bc = 1$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you know about the Schwarz lemma?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Can I apply Schwarz–Pick theorem on this?

Comment: Yes, that's why it would be nice to know your understanding of the Schwarz lemma.

Comment: There is a typo. As it stands it is obviously false. I think $Im f(z)$ shourd be $Im (z)$ on one of the two sides.

Comment: @UmbertoP. thank you! Let me try!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy u r right! Let me fix it